# session timeout handling in jquery popup window

Tags: session, timeout

I have used jquery model pop up in my application in mvc, after the session time out user should be navigate to login page, but when we click on button which opens model popup, login page is opened in the popup, it should not happend in popup, pls give me some solution for this..thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your xhr seems to get redirected to the login page, this is probably due to your server not handling session timeouts for xhrs (the xhr response is the markup of the redirect target). What techs do you use on the server side and some code (especially server side) would be nice.